# rabbitmq dont push message on queue. Node.JS

Tags: node.js, queue, rabbitmq, amqp

Here is how I make connection. Using node.js and amqp module

```
this.conn.exchange(name, options, function(ex) {
    console.log('Exchange ready');
    this.exchange = ex;

    var next = this.cb;
    delete this.cb;
    ex.publish('cbQueue', {
        id: 'asd',
        deliveryId: 'asdasd'
    });

    !!next && next(null);

}.bind(this));
```

when I run this code, it shows that exchange is ready, but on http://localhost:15672/#/queues cbQueue is empty.

Do you have idea ? why ?

Comment: Are you missing binding from exchange you are publishing to queue you'd like to route messages? From provided code I'd say you're trying to publish with routing key "cbQueue". If no binding is declared between publishing exchange and desired queue than message will not be delivered. See https://github.com/postwait/node-amqp#exchangepublishroutingkey-message-options-callback.

Answer (score 0):

most likely your code is exiting before the send to rabbitmq completes.

to test this, put a `setTimeout` around your call to `next`

```
setTimeout(function(){
  !!next && next(null);
}, 500);
```

this will delay half a second before calling next, allowing the publish to rabbitmq to complete